# Entity Framework lazy loading outside context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am using the code below to log in a user in my winform app

```
public static Boolean Attempt(String username, String password, bool salted = false)
{
        using (InventorySystemEntities context = new InventorySystemEntities(new ConfigurationManager().ConnectionString))
        {
            password = password.ToMD5(salted);

            User = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username
                                && u.Password == password && u.IsEnabled == true);
            return User != null ? true : false;
        }
}
```

is there a way to access data after the context has been disposed? like using a new context?

```
User test = Auth.Attempt(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);

//is there a way to access this?
test.UserGroup.Name;
```

Comment: You cant. If you know you are going to need the relation, you should load it eagerly. Or keep your context alive (that is if you want to get to the relation through the class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *explicit loading* to fetch the navigation property with a new context:

```
public static void LoadUserGroup(User user)
{
    using (InventorySystemEntities context = new InventorySystemEntities(
        new ConfigurationManager().ConnectionString))
    {
        context.Users.Attach(user);
        context.Entry(user).Reference(u => u.UserGroup).Load();
    }
}
```

Then you can access properties of the `UserGroup`:

```
User test = Auth.Attempt(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);

//...

Auth.LoadUserGroup(test);
test.UserGroup.Name;
```

Without creating a new context it is not possible to navigate to the `UserGroup`.